# DeclarationError: Identifier not found or not unique. function retrieve() public view returns(unit256) { ^-----^

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity

This is my second day in Solidity and I have no clue what's wrong with this code here. (I have never done any coding except some newbie level C and HTML in high school) so any help is appreciated!

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;
contract SimpleStorage {
    
    //this will get initialized as zero

    uint256 public favoritNumber;
    
    function store(uint256 _favoritNumber) public {
            favoritNumber = _favoritNumber;
    }
 
 function retrieve() public view returns(unit256) {
     return favoritNumber;
 }   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is caused by a typo.

Change the `unit256` to `uint256` (unsigned integer).